# Implementing RPC in RESTful API using DRF

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django Rest Framework to present a RESTful API. I have a router/viewset/serializer creating an endpoint for a `Person` resource:

```
/api/People/<id>/
```

I would would like some way of triggering a non-idempotent action on this resource (for example `send-email-to`). One idea I had to do so without having to re-do a lot of the routing/serialization infrastructure was to add a write-only boolean field to the serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   send_email = serializers.BooleanField(write_only=True, required=False)
```

and then add a write-only property to the model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  ...
  def do_send_email(self, value):
    # We also need to check the object is fully constructed here, I think
    if do_send_email:
        ...
  send_email = property(fset=do_send_email)
```

and then I can `PATCH` to the end point with the payload of `send_email=True`.

Is this the best way to accomplish an RPC like function using a REST API? Is this the best way to accomplish this in DRF? Ideally I would like to solve this problem having to-implement as little as possible (ie see how few lines of code the solution is). `send-email-to` is not the only action that I would like to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [extra actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) drf provides. In your case especifically, I would use @detail_route.

Something like that:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'])
def send_mail(self, request, pk=None):
    send_mail_to(pk)  # Write here your email function.
```

You have to define this function within the Person viewset so, in order to call this function, you will have to **POST** at **/people/{person_id}/send_mail** where *{person_id}* is the primary key for the person.

As a side note, since this function are synchronously called from the client and it may take a while to answer, I would recommend you the use of [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). This will allow you to call the send_mail_to function asynchronously without delaying the user response.

Comment: Let's say I want the `send_mail` procedure to take as arguments `subject` (a `String`) and `retry_count` (an `int`). I expect them to be passed in the `POST` payload. I would like to use a `Serializer` to decode the payload to the respective fields. Looking at the link that you sent as well as: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets, both samples show using a `PasswordSerializer` to decode the payload. How would I write a `Serializer` to decode this custom message format (having two fields: subject and retry_count)? Presumably, I don't have an existing `Model` like this.

Comment: Okay. The solution was to subclass `Serializer` rather than `ModelSerializer`.

Comment: Indeed, you need to define a custom serializer if the data you want to parse is different from the model itself. But, you don't need to define the Model, just the serializer with the both fields you need.