# How to create specific logic-heavy API endpoints in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a CustomEvent model, and I've added a very simple generic ListAPIView class to have standard API endpoints, including overriding `get_queryset` to take advantage of query strings.  Here is that class:

```
class EventList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    queryset = CustomEvent.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        # custom get_queryset here
        pass
```

Beyond that `/events` endpoint with basic functionality, I also want to have a very logic-heavy endpoint that also returns `CustomEvent` objects, but with some fancier logic beyond just filtering the query set.  Perhaps it performs some checks on the backend that the user has no exposure to, which filters and transforms the data that gets returned from the API.  It's not clear to me how to set out such an API endpoint with DRF... What's the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

[Extra actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) is what you need. You can specify a custom endpoint called process_event as a list_route action and define your complex view.

After defining it, you can access it under /events/process_event. You may also want to specify a custom serializer for your custom action, the set_password example in the link I provide is a good example.

And, if those jobs are heavy to process, I would recommend you to use celery.

Similar question: [Implementing RPC in RESTful API using DRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488915/implementing-rpc-in-restful-api-using-drf/26502402#26502402)